# How to display or convert and integer array in j2me?

Tags: arrays, java-me, integer

The question is quite simple but I can't find the answer.

I'm using j2me. 
I have an integer array of 9 elements.
After all the computations now I want to print it or show it in a form.

It is something like Integer.toString(); for use with an array?
I know I can use a loop but I want to know if it's a faster way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a loop but don't use the String + operator. Use StringBuffer.append().

Comment: Thanks, It works well with System.out.println. But what should I use to make it work in form.append(); ?

Comment: @user1338101 `form.append(myStringBuffer.toString())` and then `display.setCurrent(form)` - quite simple. I would recommend you to take a look at tutorials referred to at [lcdui tag wiki](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/lcdui/info)